# How do I make numbers display with spacing?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var x = document.getElementById("value").value;
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = x; 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="value"></input>
<button id="submit>Submit</button>
<p id="balance"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the numbers to be displayed like this when I press Submit:
10
100
1 000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000
10 000 000
Etc...

Comment: What have you tried so far? any code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. please have a look at here : https://www.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Are you just looking to render what you have, or is it supposed to be written to the document with JavaScript? Your tags imply the latter.  Also, is it a fixed set of numbers or arbitrary numbers?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to help me now

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatNumber(nr) {
   return nr.toString()
     .split("")
     .reverse()
     .map((n, idx) => idx % 3 === 0 ? n + " " : n)
     .reverse()
     .join("")
     .trim();
}


formatNumber(10000); // 10 000
```

Not that accurate of a function, but works nonetheless for non-decimal numbers.

There's also a **javascript library** for this:
http://numbrojs.com/format.html

Also checkout:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expression](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s12.html) for searching numbers in a string and replace it with an additional space.

```js
var i, s = '';

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    s += (i % 10);
    console.log(s.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$& '));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```